# UINavigationBar tutorial with UITable, pushing detail view using didSelectRow/RowSelected?

Tags: c#, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, monodevelop, pushviewcontroller

I have my `UITable` that works well, trying to get to another page when I select a row, havnt find toturial for this in `C #`. would be awsome if anyone knew of a good tutorial, or could explain how to do ..

Would like to understand how, in order to write the code just does not help ..

MyTableViewSource.cs

```
public override Void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
if ((indexPath.Section == 0)&&(indexPath.Row == 0))

}
```

the page I want to get to is HelloController, a `UIviewController`.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the uitableviewcontroller's navigation controller into the uitableview source then instantiate and push the new view controller in rowselected.  If you get a null exception when trying to use the navigation controller, wait to instantiate your uitableviewsource until viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear.

Comment: Assuming you are using a UITable in a UIViewController then use that viewcontroller's NavigationController (this is all assuming you have a uinavigation controller that you're using to navigate through different viewcontrollers)